# How to use LISTDSI under OMVS

Tags: zos, rexx, ispf, omvs

I am migrating some of my REXX code to run under OMVS where I've found I have no access to ISPF services or may of the TSO REXX functions.

I really need the info provided by LISTDSI - is there some way to use it under OMVS?

I'm looking to use it for z/OS datasets.

Comment: According to the documentation. " The LISTDSI function can be used only in REXX execs that run in the TSO/E address space."
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=functions-using-listdsi-function

You can invoke a rexx exec from OMVS also

Answer (score 2):

To do that type of work within USS your better option now is to use ZOAU.
`dls` command can provide the information you need with the proper options:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zoau/1.3.x?topic=commands-dls
It is the equivalent of `ls` in Unix but for datasets.

ZOAU is intended to fill the gap of automating from the USS using datasets and files in the MVS side of things. You can use ZOAU embedded in shell, Python, Java and it is easily composable.